# Coredump occurred in linux c program (Redhat 8.3.1)

Tags: c, linux, decimal, redhat, coredump

In my program, coredump occurs when using `_Decimal128` on nested structures on linux.
It occurs when all of the conditions below are met.

first, **`#pragma pack(8)`** declaration.
second, **3rd nested structure**.
third, **`_Decimal128` type address** as an argument for a function.

I'm looking for a cause of coredump.
The development environment is Redhat 8.3.1 and compiled into gcc.
The sample code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma pack(8)   // without this line, it is success

struct _c {
    int c1;
   _Decimal128 c2;
};
struct _b {
   int b1;
   _Decimal128 b2; 
   struct _c b3;      //3rd nested structure
};
struct _a {
   int a1;
   _Decimal128 a2;
   struct _b a3;     // 2nd nested structure
};

void func1(struct _c *cptr)
{
   if (cptr->c2 == 0)     // if argument type is structure, it is success
      printf("[func1]\n");
}

void func2(_Decimal128 *ptr)
{
   if (*ptr == 0)        // if argument type is _Decimal128, it occurs coredump
      printf("[func2]\n");
}

int main()
{
   struct _a a;
   struct _b b;
   _Decimal128 t = 0;
   b.b2 = t;
   b.b3.c2 = t;
   a.a3 = b;

   func1(&a.a3.b3);  // if argument is 3rd structure address, it is success
   func2(&a.a3.b2);  // if argument is _Decimal128 address of 2rd structure, it is sunccess
   func2(&a.a3.b3.c2);  // if argument is _Decimal128 address of 3rd structure, it occurs coredump
}
```

Result is,

```
[func1]
[func2]
Memory fault(coredump)
```

If I delete `#pragma pack(8)` line from the source code above, the results are as follows.

```
[func1]
[func2]
[func2]
```

Comment: Which version of GCC? Seems to work fine without changes on Godbolt's gcc 11.2. https://godbolt.org/z/9o75efq4e

Comment: Not sure with the compiled assembly code, but it seems because 1. `#pragma pack(8)` breaks the alignment rule for `_Decimal128`. 2. Working with structure pointer is fine because it notifies the compiler that `_Decimal128` cannot directly used due to the misalignment and it should be handled properly like copying. 3. Workng with `_Decimal128*` doesn't go well because compiler will assume that this is a valid (aligned) pointer for `_Decimal128` while it is actually not.

Comment: @AKX It looks the optimization is so smart that it omitted callings of the functions.

Comment: @AKX Your example is still interesting because it shows that `movdqu` (won't cause error with misalignment) is used in the function `func1` to load the value from the memory while `movdqa` (causes error with misalignment) is used in the function `func2`.

Comment: Heh, good point. Still works fine with `-O0` though, where calls definitely happen

Comment: @AKX Arguments are copied to the well-aligned stack before using `movdqa` with `-O0`.

Answer (score 4):

`#pragma pack(8)` will tell the compiler that the members of structures should be aligned to 8 bytes, ignoring the alignment requirements of each type.

`_Decimal128` may be a 16-byte type and its alignment requirement may be 16-byte.

Working with the pointer to the structure `struct _c *cptr`, the compiler can know that non-usual alignment is used for the members and that some special way may be required to handle the `_Decimal128` member.

On the other hand, working with the pointer to `_Decimal128` directly, the compiler will assume that the pointer is a valid (usually aligned) pointer to `_Decimal128` member.
Therefore it may fail when what is passed is not a normal pointer to `_Decimal128`.

Let's verify this statements with some examples.

Firstly, let's check the alignment requirement and the address of the `_Decimal128` member:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma pack(8)   // without this line, it is success

struct _c {
    int c1;
   _Decimal128 c2;
};
struct _b {
   int b1;
   _Decimal128 b2; 
   struct _c b3;      //3rd nested structure
};
struct _a {
   int a1;
   _Decimal128 a2;
   struct _b a3;     // 2nd nested structure
};

int main(void) {
    struct _a a;
    printf("sizeof(_Decimal128) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(_Decimal128));
    printf("_Alignof(_Decimal128) = %d\n", (int)_Alignof(_Decimal128));
    printf("&a = %p\n", (void*)&a);
    printf("&a.a3.b3.c2 = %p\n", (void*)&a.a3.b3.c2);
    return 0;
}
```

[An example of output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6qgYFDxJwL3F82LI):

```
sizeof(_Decimal128) = 16
_Alignof(_Decimal128) = 16
&a = 0x7fffee270d70
&a.a3.b3.c2 = 0x7fffee270da8
```

In this environment, the alignment requirement for `_Decimal128` is 16-byte, but the member `_Decimal128 c` is placed with an address that is not divisible by 16.

Secondly, here is [@AKX's example](https://godbolt.org/z/9o75efq4e) that shows the `Decimal128` may be handled differently with the function `func1` (uses a pointer to the structure) and the function `func2` (uses a pointer to `_Decimal128`):

```
func1:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movdqa  .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
        movdqu  8(%rdi), %xmm0
```

```
func2:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movdqa  .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
        movdqa  (%rdi), %xmm0
```

In this example, [the `movdqu` instruction](https://x86.puri.sm/html/file_module_x86_id_184.html) is used to load the `_Decimal128` value in the function `func1`. `movdqu` can work with unaligned memory.

On the other hand, [the `movdqa` instruction](https://x86.puri.sm/html/file_module_x86_id_183.html) is used to the `_Decimal128` value in the function `func2`. `movdqa` generates a general-protection exception on trying to work with unaligned memory.

This is suggesting that `func1` can work with unaligned memory while `func2` cannot in this example.